# How to sum all sales through Jbutton clicks in Java?

Tags: java, count, jframe, jpanel

I want to add the prices of each sale made using the calculate button and finally revealing it using a Total button. This button will give me all the sales made depending how many times I clicked the calculate button. I remember it was something like count++ or counter.

Here's what ive got.

```
public class OrderCalculatorGUI extends JFrame {
 private BagelPanel bagels;
 private ToppingPanel toppings;
 private CoffeePanel coffee;
 private GreetingPanel banner;
 private JPanel buttonPanel;
 private JButton calcButton;
 private JButton exitButton;
 private final double TAX_RATE = 0.06;

public OrderCalculatorGUI() {
    setTitle("Order Calculator");



    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    banner = new GreetingPanel();
    bagels = new BagelPanel();
    toppings = new ToppingPanel();
    coffee = new CoffeePanel();

    buildButtonPanel();

    add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(bagels, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(toppings, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(coffee, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

private void buildButtonPanel() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

    calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
    exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

    buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
    buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
}

private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double subtotal, tax, total;

        subtotal = bagels.getBagelCost() + toppings.getToppingCost() + coffee.getCoffeeCost();

        tax = subtotal * TAX_RATE;

        total = subtotal + tax;

        DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Subtotal: $" + dollar.format(subtotal) + "\n" + "Tax: $" + dollar.format(tax) + "\n" + "Total: $" + dollar.format(total));
    }
}
```

Comment: You added only UI. Spend some time thinking and writing your logic. This is a Q&A form not a "do my work forum". You should probably take some lessons from youtube or oracle website to integrate UI code with your logic.

Comment: A simple while count generic syntax would have sufficed. But thanks.